# group by in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I will try to explain myself the best I can, I have this collection  and I want to perform a "group by" on  my collection in  a way that.. having a collection that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "city": "City1",
    "population": "too many",
    "person": {//..some object..}   
  },
  {
    "city": "City1",
    "population": "too many",
    "person": {//..other object..}  
  },
  {
    "city": "City1",
    "population": "too many",
    "person": {//..another object..}    
  },
  {
    "city": "City2",
    "population": "too low",
    "person": {//..one object..}    
  }
]
```

the output would it be like this

```
[
  {
    "city": "City1",
    "population": "too many",
    "person": [
       {//..some object..},
       {//..other object..},
       {//..another object..}          
     ]
  },
  {
    "city": "City2",
    "population": "too low",
    "person":[ {//..one object..}   ]
  }
]
```

I have allready do a groupBy like this

```
db.myCollection.aggregate({
     "$group": {
     "_id": "$city",
        "resources": {
        "$push": "$person"
     }
  }
})
```

but I can't find a way to add the key "population", to each result.
(the value of population and city don't change, I mean if one value for city is "city1", the value of population will allways be "too many")

Answer (score 4):

Use mongo [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) and  [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) to find `city` presents or not and query as below :

```
 db.collectionName.aggregate({
   "$match": {
     "city": {
       "$exists": true //check city presents or not
     }
   }
 }, {
   "$group": {
     "_id": "$city", // group by city
     "data": {
       "$push": { // push all data into array 
         "name": "$name",
         "age": "$age",
         "address": "$address"
       }
     }
   }
 }, {
   "$project": {
     "city": "$_id",
     "theResults": "$data", //project them 
     "_id": 0
   }
 }).pretty()
```

**EDIT**

As per your second requirements consider your documents structure like this :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5564aaa1934833d8c1a1313f"), "city" : "City1", "person" : { "name" : "someName", "age" : "32", "address" : "Evergreen 124" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5564aaa1934833d8c1a13140"), "city" : "City1", "person" : { "name" : "someName", "age" : "32", "address" : "Evergreen 125" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5564aaa1934833d8c1a13141"), "city" : "City1", "person" : { "name" : "someName", "age" : "32", "address" : "Evergreen 126" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5564aaa1934833d8c1a13142"), "city" : "City2", "person" : { "name" : "someName", "age" : "32", "address" : "Evergreen 129" } }
```

and you should use this aggregation :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$city", //group by city
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "name": "$person.name",
        "age": "$person.age",
        "address": "$person.address"
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "city": "$_id",
    "person": "$data"
  }
}).pretty()
```

**New Edit**

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465841/mongodb-groupby) question requirement if your documents like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5564aaa1934833d8c1a1313f"), "city" : "City1", "population" : "too many", "person" : { "name" : "someName", "age" : "32", "address" : "Evergreen 124" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5564aaa1934833d8c1a13140"), "city" : "City1", "population" : "too many", "person" : { "name" : "someName", "age" : "32", "address" : "Evergreen 125" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5564aaa1934833d8c1a13141"), "city" : "City1", "population" : "too many", "person" : { "name" : "someName", "age" : "32", "address" : "Evergreen 126" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5564aaa1934833d8c1a13142"), "city" : "City2", "population" : "too low", "person" : { "name" : "someName", "age" : "32", "address" : "Evergreen 129" } }
```

then you should use following aggregation :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "city": "$city",
      "population": "$population"
    },
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "name": "$person.name",
        "age": "$person.age",
        "address": "$person.address"
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "city": "$_id.city",
    "population": "$_id.population",
    "person": "$data"
  }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: that close enogh to what I'm trying to do, but how different woult it be if the collection where like this:
`code`
    [
 {
   "city": "City1",
   "person": {//..some object..} 
 },
 {
   "city": "City1",
   "person": {//..other object..} 
 },
 {
   "city": "City1",
   "person": {//..another object..} 
 },
 {
   "city": "City2",
   "person": {//..one object..} 
 }
    ]
`code`

Comment: @flaalf I don't understand what you asking ? Is your collections having different data?